# When can I perform an elision?

Tags: classical-latin, poetry, elision

I've been reading poetry lately and sometimes, the meter just doesn't make sense. Now, I know that elision is a thing, but I don't know the rules. When can I [elide](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elision) letters? Are there any hard-and-fast rules for when elision is required, or is it all subjective and dependent on the specific poem?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Elision of a vowel (or vowel + *m*) occurs when it's at the end of the word, and the next word starts with either a vowel or *h* + vowel.

At the discretion of the poet, the last vowel of a word can be kept even if the next starts with one; in this case, it's considered to be in [hiatus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hiatus_(linguistics)). However, this is very, very rare.

However, if the second word is a form of sum, its first letter is normally elided, instead of the last letter of the preceding word. This is called prodelision.

Thanks to @Cerberus and @Nick for pointing out and naming prodelision.